# Replace array keys with values inside a string

Tags: php

I have a string of text:

```
$string = "This is a comment :) :D";
```

and an array of keys with values:

```
$smileys = Array(':)' => 'smile.gif', ':D' => 'happy.gif');
```

I want to replace any occurrences of array keys in the string with their related value so the output string would be:

```
$string = "This is a comment smile.gif happy.gif";
```

How can I do this? I've tried looping as below but no luck?

```
foreach($smileys as $smiley){

    $string = preg_replace("~\b$smileys\b~", $smileys[$smiley], $string);

}
```

**Edit**

I also wish to add some html between the array and replace so:

```
:D
```

turns into

```
<img src="/happy.gif" />
```

but would the same html need to be in every array value if `strtr` were used?

Comment: Sounds like a simple string replace should work - no need for regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
$string= strtr($string,$smileys);
```

This will walk through `$string` and replace each occurence of each key in `$smileys` with the associated value.

**Edit:**

To include the `<img>` tags into the string you could post-process the whole string with a single

```
$string=preg_replace('/([\w]+\.gif)/i','<img src="$1">',$string);
```

This of course relies on the assumption that all your gif names do not contain any blanks and that there are no other words like `image.gif` in your string since they would be affected too ...

Comment: How about if I want to do the equivalent of: `$string= strtr($string, "<img src=\"$smileys\">");` second parameter has to be an array so would I just have to change every array value or is there another way to do array value and some html?

Comment: Just change the array. `$smileys = Array(':)' => '<img src="smile.gif">', ':D' => '<img src="happy.gif">');`

Comment: @BenFortune Okay I thought that's what would need doing, only issue is there's 70+ array items so it adds quite a bit of repetitive html.

Comment: @cars10 That g shouldn't be in there. ;)

Comment: `pcre_replace` too. :)

Comment: @BenFortune time to call it a day ... my concentration is gone!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($smileys as $key => $value)
{
  str_replace($key,$value,$string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
foreach($smileys as $key=>$value){
    $string = str_replace($smiley[$key], $smiley[$value], $string);
}
```

Comment: What do you propose if his array was containing 50 smileys ? :)